# Font Issues Upon Export From QGIS 1.9

Tags: qgis, export

I'm using QGIS 1.9.0-Master, code revision 1570240.

I know I shouldn't be using it for 'production' but I'm working on a map layout, and all of the new composer features are very helpful!  As of the version available in OSGEO4W (I think) last Thursday, I was able to export my map properly to either PDF or an image. However, when I try with a version from yesterday or today, the font is not being exported properly. See examples below of proper exporting (top image) and the current export (bottom image):

[image]

[image]

I tried via OSGEO4W to roll back to a previous version, but it did not install properly for some reason.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58392/problem-with-labels-on-export-print-a-map-qgis-master), and fixed in the latest 1.9 release. No longer an issue.