# Problem with labels on export/print a map (qgis master)

Tags: qgis, print-composer

As you can see on the images below, the labels on the exported map (right) are much bigger then in the original map (left). Same by pdf, image, and vector - export.

[image]

Whats the problem? Can I fall back in the qgis master version to the version of about 1 month ago?

Comment: I confirm this problem with recent versions of Master. As you mention, it applies to all composer export formats. QGIS Master from Nightly, Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit) in my case.

Comment: It's a known issue, see: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/7627

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been fixed in this morning's download. Master from the nightly repository, Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit).